# How to create java object from json

Tags: java, json, jackson

How can I create this json content recursively using a java object and Jackson ? :

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "cluster",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
                            "size": 3938
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "TestCLuster",
                            "size": 3938
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "name": "analytics"
        }
    ],
    "name": "flare"
}
```

Here is my object structure so far, a parent named DendogramVO and a child class named Children which also has a children List :

```
import java.util.List;

public class DendogramVO {
    private List<Children> children;
    private String name;

    public List<Children> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Children> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

import java.util.List;

public class Children {

    private List<Children> children;
    private String name;

    public List<Children> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Children> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your JSON contains unknown properties. You need to configure the `ObjectMapper` not to fail when it comes across them (or add them to your class)

```
String s="{ \"children\": [ { \"children\": [ { \"name\": \"cluster\", \"children\": [ { \"name\": \"AgglomerativeCluster\", \"size\": 3938 }, { \"name\": \"TestCLuster\", \"size\": 3938 } ] } ], \"name\": \"analytics\" } ], \"name\": \"flare\"}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Children children = mapper.readValue(s, Children.class);

System.out.println(children.getChildren());
```

with a simple `Children#toString()` prints

```
[[children = [[children = [[children = null, name = AgglomerativeCluster], [children = null, name = TestCLuster]], name = cluster]], name = analytics]]
```

Comment: Children#toString() does not match the json tree structure that I have posted in question?

Comment: @user470184 Yeah it does. The most nested json object contains a json array that contains two json objects. It has the name `cluster`. The object that contains it has a name `analytics`. And that object is `children`. If you do `children.getName()` in the code above, it will print `flare`, which is the name of the root json object.

Comment: have you tried your code , mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); causes compiler error : "The method configure(SerializationConfig.Feature, boolean) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the 
 arguments (DeserializationFeature, boolean)"

Comment: @user470184 [Upgrade to new version of Jackson.](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core)

Comment: I'm using latest but this compiler error : "The method configure(SerializationConfig.Feature, boolean) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the 
 arguments (DeserializationFeature, boolean)" on line "mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);"

Comment: @user470184 Your `ObjectMapper` should be in package `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`.

Comment: children.toString prints com.data.Children@7ddeef8a, also, the generated json structure is not correct as it contains null values which the original json structure does not contain

Comment: @user470184 Stop being so negative and start analyzing. Implement your own `toString()` method like I did, quote _with a simple `Children#toString()`_. As for the `null`, check your two most nested elements. They don't have `children` and so the field is `null`. If you want it to be an empty list instead, add `= new LinkedList<>()` to your `children` field.

Comment: apologies if I came across as being negative, I did not realise Children#toString() means to implement my own toString implementation. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user470184 No problem. You should always think of implementing the `toString()` for debug purposes. Was the solution what you were looking for?

Comment: I thought I could use jackson to print exactly the json object structure I posted in question using just java objects so  if there are null values then "children = null" would not be printed. But it seems I will need to write my own toString implementation to achieve this (which is fine).

Comment: @user470184 There might be a `SerializationFeature` for that.